# Parse SQL script as 2005 in 2012?

Tags: sql-server, management-studio-express

In SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, is there a way to to parse my SQL as SQL Server 2005 syntax? My development PC has SQL Server 2012 Express but the production server uses 2005. I have to hook into a 2005 development server to run my tests before pushing to production.

It would be really nice if I could test for SQL Server 2005 correctness from a 2012 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Compatibility Level.

For 2005, use COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 90

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

refer to here for more information
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to do this temporarily inside the current script/transaction?

Comment: no. this is a one-off command. You can create a database and set it to 90 for your testing before deployment.

Comment: It's a pity there's no way to run an ad-hoc test for 2005 syntax